# onTouchListener for piano app

Tags: android, audio, ontouchlistener, soundpool

I'm trying to build a piano application.

How do I make it possible to slide across multiple keys (VIEWS) and make them play their tone?
Every key has it's own sound.

Will this make a big performance difference?

**Right now this is working:**

- Play audio -> MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
- Stop audio -> MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
- Show touch feedback -> MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
- Revert touch feedback -> MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
- Sustain the audio when a toggle button is checked
- When I touch a key and move away from the key the sound stops.

Here is one of the keys:

```
    keyC1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private Rect rect;    // Variable rect to hold the bounds of the view

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Finger started pressing --> play sound in loop mode
                    rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
                    Sound_tonC1();
                    keyC1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgray));
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    // Finger released --> stop playback
                    if(!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())){
                        // User moved outside bounds
                        keyC1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piano_whitekey);

                        if(!sustain){
                            spool.stop(streamID_C1);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Finger released --> stop playback
                    keyC1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piano_whitekey);

                    if(!sustain){
                        spool.stop(streamID_C1);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is vital to understand is that when you press down on an object and move your finger off the object, the event that is called is an ACTION_CANCEL event. This is why when you press on any element in an app but slide your finger off the app, the action you were going to perform doesn't happen. So, you should handle the cancel event in your code and put the ACTION_UP code in that case as well:

```
keyC1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    boolean keyIsPressed = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Finger started pressing --> play sound in loop mode
                Sound_tonC1();
                keyIsPressed = true;
                keyC1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgray));
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                // Finger released --> stop playback
                keyC1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piano_whitekey);

                if(!sustain){
                    keyIsPressed = false;
                    spool.stop(streamID_C1);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Finger released --> stop playback
                keyC1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.piano_whitekey);

                if(!sustain){
                    keyIsPressed = false;
                    spool.stop(streamID_C1);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // Finger is moving on key --> start playback if the key is not already played
                if(!keyIsPressed) {
                    Sound_tonC1();
                    keyIsPressed = true;
                    keyC1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgray));
                }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Note: use ACTION_CANCEL and get rid of ACTION_MOVE as you don't need to handle move events for a key, just when it is pressed down and when it is released.

The reason your code wasn't detecting when the finger left the key was because once the touch event leaves the area, your object no longer receives any of the events. Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I detect that a user move his finger from key #1 to key#2? I would like to trigger the next sound when the user slide his finger to key #2

Comment: What you should do is use the ACTION_MOVE mask to detect when the finger moves to the next key and if the key is not playing, play the note. If a finger slides from outside a view onto a view, ACTION_DOWN does not get called, but ACTION_MOVE will. I've updated my answer with a solution.

Comment: ACTION_CANCEL does not seems to be called

Comment: Try removing the check for the ACTION_MASK (see answer)

Comment: Do you have any other tips? ACTION_CANCEL is never called